# Select Specific Text In Cell - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking to extract a specific section of text from a cell.

The cell content looks like this;
`"modified":"1595515574184000","owner_id":"xxxx","priority_id":"xxx","severity_id":"xxx","status_id":"xxxx","type_id":"xxxx","user_email":"xxx","user_id":"xxxx","verifier_id":"xxxxx"`

All the content is presented in this format however, the items are not always in the same order so functions such as `left()`, `right()` & `mid()` will not work for me.

I've also tried using the `split()` function, but it produces an array of items in different columns

In the above cell I'd like to extract the 16 digits after every "modified" tag.

If anyone has any suggestions or feedback let me know!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to add on to player0's answer above (which is already correct). I always prefer on always using specific number of repetition instead of using `+` and `*` when we are already sure of the length of the wanted string we want to extract. This way, we can always have the exact answer we are looking for and it will also act as data checker since it will error out if it will not follow the strict pattern `"modified":"<16 digit>"`. I'd use this:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, """modified"":""(\d{16})""")
```

If you do not want it to be strict, then player0's 2nd answer should be great.

Comment: \d+ will not import anything more after digits nor anything less than the chunk of digits. specifying it to \d{16} would be only contra productive if by any chance there are less than 16 digits resulting in error or more than 16 digits - not extracting it completly

Comment: Thanks for the input @player0. I do understand that that's the downside of doing the specific number of repetitions. I use this since OP mentioned the length of the digits, and also, this is also a good way of checking if the extracted string is within the expected output since it will error out if the digit is not exactly 16. That's why I mentioned `when we are already sure of the length`. This will act as data checking at the same time. It is up to OP if this will be applicable to the use case he'd like to use or not. It's just my personal preference when it comes to data like this.

Comment: Thumb up! Works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\d+")
```

[image]

or:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "modified...(\d+)")
```

[image]